# Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer`2.CreateNativeControl' not found

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm creating a cross-platform app for school and i've encountered this error:

Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ViewRenderer`2.CreateNativeControl' not found.

It's triggered when i try to render my location page.

[LocationPage.xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5SdM.png)

Anyone who know how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have added the `Xamarin.Forms.Maps` package to **BOTH** your PCL and your Android projects. This is the most common reason for errors like this.

Second, make sure you've properly added your Google Maps API key(s) to your Android project.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWValueGoesHere" />
```

Third, make sure you called init on the maps from your Android project:

```
Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);
```

Last but not least, make sure all your nuget packages are up to date with versions that play well with each other.

Comment: Hi, i've added Xamarin.Forms.Maps in my global package map, in the android package map and in the IOS package map. 

I forgot my API key but that is fixed know, thanks to you.

I called the init in android and IOS project. 

But still the same error.

Comment: Do you have the Android SDK updated? What versions of Xamarin.Forms and Android are you using?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms 2.3.3.175
Android 6.0

Comment: It's randomly fixed today. I can go to my location page and the map appears on it, but don't load. I don't know why it's working now but thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: @SuavePirate Any other suggestion? I've followed directions in your post, there are no compiler warnings, etc. etc. My app only crashes when I try to show the map on my Droid project.

Comment: Are you using an actual phone or an emulator? This could be an issue with Google play services not being loaded on the device if it is an emulator. Could you also post the entire stacktrace of the error?

Comment: @SuavePirate I didn't have my initial test project, so I added it to a work in progress, and this happened: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710697/xamarin-forms-how-to-fix-broken-build-seems-like-formsmap-broke-it