# Xamarin Forms - how to fix broken build? (seems like FormsMap broke it)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono, xamarin.forms

After installing Xamarin Forms Map, I am now getting this. I've tried to remove everything I added (the init, changes to the Manifest, etc). Gone from a working solution to a broken one that won't even compile.

Appreciate any suggestions

Tried to install current version of Xamarin.Forms.Map : 2.3.3.180

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets (_GenerateJavaStubs target) ->
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:  warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.OS.CancellationSignal+IOnCancelListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.OS.CancellationSignal+IOnCancelListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:  warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.OS.CancellationSignal.IOnCancelListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.OS.CancellationSignal+IOnCancelListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:  warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider+ISubUiVisibilityListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider+ISubUiVisibilityListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:  warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider.ISubUiVisibilityListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider+ISubUiVisibilityListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:  warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider+IVisibilityListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider+IVisibilityListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:  warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider.IVisibilityListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.View.ActionProvider+IVisibilityListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:  warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.IOnApplyWindowInsetsListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.IOnApplyWindowInsetsListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:  warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.View.IOnApplyWindowInsetsListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.View.IOnApplyWindowInsetsListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:  warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:  warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:  warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:  warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorUpdateListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:  warning : Duplicate managed type found! Mappings between managed types and Java types must be unique. First Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.MenuItemCompat+IOnActionExpandListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'; Second Type: 'Android.Support.V4.View.MenuItemCompat+IOnActionExpandListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
    /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:  warning : References to the type 'Android.Support.V4.View.MenuItemCompat.IOnActionExpandListenerImplementor' will refer to 'Android.Support.V4.View.MenuItemCompat+IOnActionExpandListenerImplementor, Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Errors:

/Users/TESTProjects/TEST/Droid/TEST.Droid.csproj (Build) ->
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets (_CompileJava target) ->
    obj/Debug/android/src/mono/android/support/v4/app/SharedElementCallback_OnSharedElementsReadyListenerImplementor.java(8,47):  javacerror :  error: cannot find symbol

android.support.v4.app.SharedElementCallback.OnSharedElementsReadyListener
  symbol:   class OnSharedElementsReadyListener
  location: class SharedElementCallback


obj/Debug/android/src/mono/android/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManagerCompat_AccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor.java(8,67):  javacerror :  error: cannot find symbol
        android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat.AccessibilityStateChangeListener
  symbol:   class AccessibilityStateChangeListener
  location: class AccessibilityManagerCompat


obj/Debug/android/src/mono/android/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManagerCompat_TouchExplorationStateChangeListenerImplementor.java(8,67):  javacerror :  error: cannot find symbol
        android.support.v4.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat.TouchExplorationStateChangeListener
  symbol:   class TouchExplorationStateChangeListener
  location: class AccessibilityManagerCompat


obj/Debug/android/src/mono/android/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompat_OnCloseListenerImplementor.java(8,45):  javacerror :  error: cannot find symbol
        android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompat.OnCloseListener
  symbol:   class OnCloseListener
  location: class SearchViewCompat

obj/Debug/android/src/mono/android/support/v4/widget/SearchViewCompat_OnQueryTextListenerImplementor.java(8,45): error :  error: cannot find symbol
        android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompat.OnQueryTextListener
  symbol:   class OnQueryTextListener
  location: class SearchViewCompat
```

Comment: Have tried to add/remove the maps again, remove the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.* packages as well, to no avail.

Rather frustrating when the tooling vendor's own 1st party packages break a working project ....

Comment: Have you also tried removing the android support libraries? Looks like most of the conflicts are from that.

Comment: @SuavePirate - thanks, but which libraries, all of the Xamarin ones in the Droid app? Would I just add those packages again?

Comment: All of the Android.Support ones such as `Xamarin.Android.Support.v4`

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Removed them all (packages folder was empty); added XF back in (dependancies caused the Xamarin.android.* to added back; added the share plugin  -- and still 5 errors:

/Users/martenliebster/Projects/QV/Droid/obj/Debug/android/src/mono/android/support/v4/app/SharedElementCallback_OnSharedElementsReadyListenerImplementor.java(47,47): Error:  error: cannot find symbol
  android.support.v4.app.SharedElementCallback.OnSharedElementsReadyListener
  symbol:   class OnSharedElementsReadyListener
  location: class SharedElementCallback
 (QV.Droid)

Comment: AccessibilityManagerCompat_AccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor.java(67,67): Error:  error: cannot find symbol --- AccessibilityManagerCompat_TouchExplorationStateChangeListenerImplementor.java(67,67): Error:  error: cannot find symbol --- SearchViewCompat_OnCloseListenerImplementor.java(45,45): Error:  error: cannot find symbol --- SearchViewCompat_OnQueryTextListenerImplementor.java(45,45): Error:  error: cannot find symbol

Comment: One example: SharedElementCallback_OnSharedElementsReadyListenerImplementor.java -- public class SharedElementCallback_OnSharedElementsReadyListenerImplementor
 extends java.lang.Object
 implements
  mono.android.IGCUserPeer,
  android.support.v4.app.SharedElementCallback.OnSharedElementsReadyListener 

After the SharedElementCallback in the last line there's the red squigglies error lines and "error: cannot find symbol" in red.

Comment: I restarted; same issue still; I was able to compile & run the sample Hanselman app.

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into the same problem today, which seems to be related to two different dependencies from two C# projects of which one is used/referenced by the other. From what I see, there may be two different versions of the same dependency installed. Most likely, you might need to consolidate your NuGet packages. This might be what the error message is trying to say. One of the duplicated types is `Android.Support.V4.View.IViewPropertyAnimatorListenerImplementor` which is contained within the two libraries **Xamarin.Android.Support.v4** and **Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat**.
At least for my solution this is due to two different versions of the **Xamarin.Android.Support.v4** NuGet package, namely versions 25.3.1 and 23.3.0. Because of the dependencies of the [Xamarin.Forms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/) NuGet package, I explicitly had to downgrade to version 23.3.0 which seems to solve the problem.